# Expand grid in R with paste

Tags: r, function

I am trying to analyse a dataframe using hierarchical clustering `hclust` function in R.

I would like to pass in a vector of `p` values I'll write beforehand (maybe something like `c(5/4, 3/2, 7/4, 9/4)`) and be able to have these specified as the different p value options with Minkowski distance when I use `expand.grid`. Ideally, when `hyperparams` is viewed, it would also be clear which value of p has been used for each `minkowski`, i.e. they should be labelled. So for example, where (if you run my code for `hyperparams`) there would currently just be one `minkowski` under Dists, for each of the methods in Meths, there would be, if I supplied the `p` vector as `c(5/4, 3/2, 7/4, 9/4)`, now instead 4 rows for Minkowski distance: `minkowski, p=5/4`, `minkowski, p=3/2`, `minkowski, p=7/4`, `minkowski, p=9/4` (or looking something like that, making the p values clear). Any ideas?

(Note: no packages please, only base R!)

**Edit:** I worded it poorly before, now rewritten. Let's take the following example instead:

```
acc <- function(x){
  first = sum(x)
  second = sum(x^2)
  return(list(First=first,Second=second))
}
iris0 <- iris
iris1 <- cbind(log(iris[,1:4]),iris[5])
iris2 <- cbind(sqrt(iris[,1:4]),iris[5])
```

Now the important bit:

```
tests <- expand.grid(Dists=c("euclidean","maximum","manhattan","canberra","binary"),
                     DS=c("iris0","iris1","iris2"))

Table <- Map(function(x, ds){acc(table(ds$Species, cutree(hclust(dist(get(ds)[,1:4], method=x)),3)))},tests[[1]], tests[[2]])
```

This will work. But now if I want to include a term like `"minkowski",p=3` in expand.grid, how would I do it?

```
tests <- expand.grid(Dists=c("euclidean","maximum","manhattan","canberra","binary","minkowski,p=3"),
                     DS=c("iris0","iris1","iris2"))

Table <- Map(function(x, ds){acc(table(ds$Species, cutree(hclust(dist(get(ds)[,1:4], method=x)),3)))},tests[[1]], tests[[2]])
```

This gives an error.

In reality there should be no `p` argument unless the `method="minkowski"`. I have tried to use `strsplit` to get the first part of the expression into ds, and a `switch` with `strsplit` to get the second part and then use `parse` (it would return NULL if the length of the strsplit was not 2 -- this should pass no argument, I think). The issue seems to be that `strsplit` is not `strsplit(x,",")` fails to evaluate the vectorized x but rather tries to evaluate the character `x` which is not a string. Can anyone suggest any workaround/fix or other method for including the `minkowski,p=1.6` terms and the like?

Comment: I  am not getting any error with the example

Comment: @akrun The post is rewritten. I am wondering if you know a fix for this, since you suggested the eval(parse(text=) method which I would need along with ```strsplit``` (though your method yesterday was for ```sub``` I think ```strsplit``` is similar in that respect). Do you have any ideas for this one?

Comment: Can you check my update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a 'p' value column

```
tests <- expand.grid(Dists=c("euclidean","maximum","manhattan","canberra","binary",
        "minkowski3", "minkowski4", "minkowski5"),
               DS=c("iris0","iris1","iris2"))
```

Suppose, we have another column of 'p' values in 'tests', the above solution can be changed to

```
tests$p <- as.list(args(dist))$p # default value
i1 <- grepl("minkowski", tests$Dists)
tests$Dists <- sub("[0-9.]+$", "", tests$Dists)

tests$p[i1] <- rep(3:5, length.out = sum(i1))
Map(function(x, ds, p){       
    dist1 <-  dist(get(ds)[, 1:4], method = x, p = p)          
    ct <- cutree(hclust(dist1), 3)
    acc(table(get(ds)$Species, ct))},
       as.character(tests[[1]]), as.character(tests[[2]]), tests$p )
```

Comment: Thanks. But it works to test only 1 Minkowski p-value, right? It would be better to be able to include multiple Minkowski p-values within the ```tests``` and get combinations of them with the datasets. I guess the question comes down to whether it's possible to have a ```strsplit``` or other splitting method read/operate on the variable from Map (i.e. ```"euclidean","maximum",...```) rather than the variable name (```x```).

Comment: @MobeusZoom i would not make it complicated by a single stirng.  You can add a new argument to `Map` having the `p` as a vector i.e. `as.character(tests[[1]]), as.character(tests[[2]]), p1)` and instead of the `p <- if....` remove it, and just specify the `p = p` also `function(x, ds, p)`

Comment: @MobeusZoom you can do that with `strsplit`, but it is much more cleaner if you create a new vector or a new column in 'tests'

Comment: Once you put the ```p``` in ```tests```, how would you go about ensuring it is read as an argument inside ```dist``` only if ```method="minkowski"```, and otherwise for any other dist method the ```p``` argument is ```NULL``` (or passed over)? (When ```method``` is in general varying over ```x```.) I agree such a solution would be really neat! (Much better than "minkowski,p=3","minkowski,p=4" etc which I was imagining.) Maybe you could update your answer to comment on this case. such as having a vector of p values ```p=seq(3,10)``` in your ```tests``` for example.

Comment: @MobeusZoom in that case, there is no need for `if/else` because you are providing a vector or 'p' for each element of 'tests'

Comment: Okay issue is that we want to try a vector of **different** p-values with Minkowski distance. Like ```method="minkowski",p=3```, then ```method="minkowski",p=4```, ... up to ```method="minkowski",p=10```, trying them all with each dataset ```DS```. So just setting one for all occurrences of ```minkowski``` wouldn't do that. Also I'm not sure we can set ```p=2``` for the other dist methods with impunity...(?) it might be best to try to avoid setting any p at all, or NULL p, for ```method=``` anything but "minkowski". We could do that with ```switch``` I think.

Comment: @MobeusZoom just replace the `tests$p <- ifelse(tests$Dists == 'minkowski', 3, 2)` with `tests$p <- c(3, 5, 3, 2, 3, 4, ....)`

Comment: @MobeusZoom `2` is the default p value if you check `as.list(args(dist))$p` i.e. if you don't set any `p` value the default option is used.  Please check `dist` on your console, the arguments are `function (x, method = "euclidean", diag = FALSE, upper = FALSE, 
    p = 2) `

Comment: (1) Thanks you've convinced me on the ```as.list(args(dist))$p```. It's fine as ```2```.     (2) I tried tests$p <- ifelse(tests$Dists == 'minkowski', c(3,4,5), 2). It only replaced all the p vals for Minkowski with ```5```. As for just ```tests$p <- c(3, 5, 3, 2, 3, 4, ....)```, firstly I'd have to manually select rows with Minkowski (problematic if I have hundreds of rows), secondly it doesn't let me expand ```tests``` as I need. e.g. I want to test ```"minkowski",p=3``` with **each** dataset ```iris0```, ```iris1```, ```iris2```, same for ```"minkowski",p=4``` etc. to 10.

Comment: rather than just ```iris0``` with ```"minkowski",p=3```, then ```iris1``` with ```"minkowski",p=4``` which setting it as a vector does

Comment: @MobeusZoom that wouldn't work, If you have only 3 elements of 'minkowski, i.e. `tests$p <- 2; tests$p[tests$Dists == 'minkowski'] <- c(3, 4, 5)`

Comment: @MobeusZoom if you have 100s of rows of 'minkowski', do a join or use a named vector

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213887/discussion-between-mobeus-zoom-and-akrun).

Comment: @MobeusZoom you can just do `tests$p <- 2; i1 <- tests$Dists == 'minkowski'; tests$p[i1] <- setNames(c(3, 4, 5), paste0("iris", 0:2))[as.character(tests$DS)[i1]]`